# Rails: combining optional params into a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a view with a huge paginated list of records that need filtering.

Users can filter by records a few different ways (such as 'saved' records, 'read' records, and 'mark deleted' records) and I'd like for them to be able to **combine** these filters any possible way.

My current, flawed, non-functioning approach. The code below does not produce anything unless all of the params are specified and valid:

```
#view. Set the 'se' filter to true; leave all others as is 
<%= link_to list_url(:id=>params[:id], :se=>"true", :st=>params[:st], :re=>params[:re]) do %> 
  <div class="button">Toggle SE</div>
<% end %>

#controller query. Add whichever params are passed into the conditions for the new page.
#query is paginated and sorted
@records = Record.where("user_id IN (?) AND see = ? AND star = ? AND delete = ? AND like = ?", @users.select("id"), params[:se], params[:st], params[:re]).paginate :page => params[:page], :order => (sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
```

What is the best way to create this filtering system?
I imagine a client-side sort would be faster than asking the server to become involved every time - is there a simple AJAX way to accomplish this kind of thing? Imagine filters the user can **toggle on and off** in any combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
conditions = {:user_id => @users.select("id")}
{
 :se => :see,
 :st => :star,
 :del => :delete
}.each{|k1, k2| conditions[k2] = params[k1] unless params[k1].blank?}

@records = Record.where(conditions).paginate(...)
```

The `conditions` hash will be filled based on the values present in the `params` hash.

**Edit 1**

You can combine conditions hash and array.

```
@records = Record.where(conditions).where(
  ":created_at > ?",  Date.today - 30).paginate(...)
```

You can change the user_id condition to what ever you want by specifying

```
conditions[:user_id] = @user.id
```

In the above statement, if the RHS is an array, rails automatically generates the `IN` clause. Otherwise, equality check(`=`) is performed.

Comment: This is awesome! One last thing - how do you add the condition :created_at > Date.today - 30? I assume if :user_id => @users.select("id"), the other version :user_id => @user.id would also work?

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: But could you please explain how this works in Rails ``@records = Record.where(conditions).where([":created_at > ?",  Date.today - 30])`` - does it mean 2 queries to MySQL? (it isn't effective if so)

Comment: OK I found an answer already (no, there are now multiple queries to DB): http://stackoverflow.com/a/10747692/530514

Comment: @oyatek it results in just one SQL. The link that you referred to also implies that.

Answer (score 0):

Can also use Anonymous scopes: [Combine arrays of conditions in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251919/combine-arrays-of-conditions-in-rails/4860480#4860480)

Comment: A link in the ref'd post is gone, and they the code was not included in the answer.